# The memoryless property of exponential distribution

Tags: statistics, exponential-distribution

Let $Z$ be an exponential random variable and $R$ an independent nonnegative random variable. Show that
$$
P(Z-R > u | Z > R ) = P(Z > u)
$$
From here, I can use Bayes Theorem to split the Left Hand Side, and I know that I have to integrate them.

However, I'm not sure how to exactly to proceed from here. I know that $u \geq 0$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!